# Google Sheets: ArrayFormula: Alternative To AND()

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I understand that using AND() within an ArrayFormula doesn't work, but I haven't found an alternative that I understand.

[image]
In col U I have entered an ordinary formula which is copied down the rows. In col T, I wrapped it in an ArrayFormula, which does not work.

I've read on this forum about using "multiplication of truth values" instead, but have no understanding what that means, let alone how to implement it.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123729/multiple-if-statements-with-between-number-ranges-alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF((A2:A13>=58)*(A2:A13<=68), A2:A13, 
       IF((B2:B13>=58)*(B2:B13<=68), B2:B13, )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works fine, but I don't understand it. Need to study INDEX() for a start I guess.  Does the multiplication part do something like "if TRUE*TRUE then..." ?

Comment: @maxhugen index is type of arrayformula so either you use arrayformula or shorter index. and yes for the multiplication because arrayformula does not support AND and OR functions